# Automatically opening kwallet while logging in to KDE

Tags: debian, kde, kwallet

How can I configure kwallet to automatically open when I log in to KDE, so that I don't have to retype my password every time I want to connect to a wireless network or when Chrome needs some passwords, etc.?

I am running KDE 4.6.5 in Debian testing.

Comment: [*Bug 92845 - KWallet should use PAM to make single-sign-on possible*](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92845) This is so 2004. No really, maybe the discussion thread is helpful. (No idea what's the solution, though, maybe KSecretService will fix this?)

Comment: @sr_, thanks for the link. It looks rather grim :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just converted to Kubuntu from Xubuntu on Precise. Chose kdm as display manager and doing so at next login was presented with 3 password entries in total - kdm login screen then gnome-keyring for Ubuntu One and kwallet for Chromium. Crazyness!

So my solution currently is:
 1) use LightDM instead of KDM which unlocks gnome-keyring automatically
 2) set up kwallet with blank password
 3) use home folder encryption

Comment: I am not using gnome-keyring on my Kubuntu setup. Installing LightDM does not unlock my KWallet on login. What else do I need to configure?

Comment: @gertvdijk, so which additional password prompt do You get? Also, read my answer once more, it doesn't suggest that LightDM will unlock KWallet.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Sorry, I thought that you were listing several options.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no concern for security you can remove the password on a wallet and it will open without prompting.

Comment: Well, I don't really want to go that far...

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a discussion on the KDE forums about [automatically opening Kwallet on login](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=39258). Apparently there is an OpenSuse package to do this, and the Gnome password manager already has this behaviour.